# Даны длины сторон треугольника a, b, c. Найти медианы треугольника, сторонами которого являются медианы исходного треугольника

Tags: c++

Даны длины сторон треугольника a, b, c. Найти медианы треугольника, сторонами  которого являются медианы исходного треугольника. Вычисление  медианы оформить в виде процедуры.

Написал программу, которая ниже, но она не работает, пишет ошибку "использована неинициализированная локальная переменная d,e,f". Но я не знаю, какие числа необходимо присвоить, ведь значения не даны.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double med(double a, double b, double c, double m) {
    return 0, 5 * sqrt(2 * pow(b, 2) + 2 * pow(c, 2) - a * a);
}

int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    double e;
    double f;

    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    med(a, b, c, d);
    med(b, c, a, e);
    med(c, a, b, f);
    med(d, e, f, a);
    med(e, f, d, b);
    med(f, d, e, c);

    cout << a << b << c;
}
```

Comment: Самое простое - просто проинициализировать эти переменные нулями. Кроме того, параметр `m` в функции `med` никак не используется - его надо скорее всего вовсе убрать. Более того, вот это выражение `0, 5 * sqrt(2 * pow(b, 2) + 2 * pow(c, 2) - a * a);` имеет своим результатом `5 * sqrt(...`, так как тут у тебя используется оператор запятая, который отбрасывает первый аргумент (0 в этом случае) и возвращает второй. Скорее всего имелось в виду `0.5` - с точкой.

Comment: правильно пишет, для чего у ваc переменная m в med?

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov, да, спасибо, убрал, я проинициализировал переменные нулями. Но теперь он жалуется на строки 20-25 (слишком много аргументов в вызове функции), и ещё раз на строки 20-25 (med: функция не принимает 4 аргументов)

Comment: @smirnoffmv ну так естественно :) Надо ж и из вызова убрать аргументы `med(a, b, c);`